# Print star ('*') diamond in C with nested loops?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, nested

I want to be able to print a diamond like this when the user enters 5 for the diamond. But also will work for any value that is odd and greater than 0.

[image]

I have a code that works to make a diamond for user input of 5 but won't work for all odd number inputs..

```
 half = (size/2)+1;

 for (a=1; a <=  half ; a++) /*top to mid row of diamond*/
   {
     for (b=a; b<half;b++)
       {
     printf(" ");
       }
     for (c= size -2* a; c <=  half; c++)
       {
     printf("*");
       } 
      printf("\n");
   }
 for (a = 1; a < half;a++)
   {
     for (b = a; b>0;b--)
       {
     printf(" ");
       }
     for (c = size-2*a; c >0 ;c--)
       {
     printf("*");
       }
     printf("\n");
   }


  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank you.

Mike

Comment: you don't need nested loops, how about two loops, one that increments and one that decrements, try that and report back with your attempt.

Comment: Google is full of results and examples of this ("C print diamond"), what have you tried so far?

Comment: Try asking to yourself the following questions: How many spaces and then asterisks do you need to print for the first line? How many spaces and asterisks will you need each line, comparing with the previous line? At a certain point you'll need to print more spaces and less asterisks: when?

Comment: Re-tagged as homework. Not trying to be offensive, but this is dead simple if you sit down and think about it for 5 minutes.

Comment: @Dogbert, that's a rather dangerous assumption. I'm sure most pathology nurses consider drawing blood to be "dead simple" but it's not something I'd try. People here have vastly different levels of skill in various areas.

Comment: There is an interesting twist on this question in a Deitel C++ book (but same thing can be done in C). Once you're able to print arbitrarily sized diamonds, try doing the same thing, but with only one loop. That exercise made me feel *really* good once I worked out how to do it and adjusted everything properly.

Comment: @chris, at some point that becomes counter-productive. While it's often clever to be able to grok stuff like that (and I have to admit I've felt that before), it's kind of an arbitrary limitation which you're unlikely to meet in the real world. Similar to the swapping variables without a temporary variable (xor trick), the inability to use a temporary is unlikely, as is the inability to have a program where only one loop is allowed :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, the book just included that as a bonus, and my teacher did too when we got to it. That was my most well-deserved bonus mark I've ever worked for. It really makes you think about it in a totally different way, which is probably the main point of it. I spent how long sitting there 100% sure that I needed two loops, until it finally came to me.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I did that question at 8 years of age from a Steve Prata book; C++ Primer Plus if I recall correctly, and it was manageable then. Provided loops and printf are covered in the first 3 chapters of the text this individual used (which is the case in 90% of 'traditional' C/C++ books), this person has everything needed on-hand to solve this question. I stand by my original statement and having re-tagged this. I posed this question to 12 year-olds learning basic Flash programming, and they figured it out as a group in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly homework so here's a clue.

Count the number of spaces before a line and the number of stars in that line.  What you're looking for is a relationsip between the line number and those two values.

Then you can use two consecutive `for` loops, one increasing the star count and the other decreasing it.

*Within* each of those loops would be two *more* consecutive loops to print out the required number of spaces followed by the required number of stars followed by a newline character.

---

If you're still having trouble after reading the above, consider this. For an input of (odd, as you state you enforce in your comments) `n`, the space count starts at `(n - 1) / 2` and the star count at `1`. For each subsequent line, the space count reduces by `1` and the star count increases by `2`.

That works up until the point where the space count reaches `0`, then you turn around and go the other way, making sure you don't print that middle line twice.

Once the star count reaches `0`, you're done.

Now you just have to turn that specification into code :-)

---

Now, since you've indicated in comments that you're interested in making your own solution rather than just being handed code, I feel comfortable giving you something you can check your own solution against. Here's the pseudo-code I would use:

```
# Input data, check and init counters.

input n
make sure n is odd and greater than 2
set numspaces to (n-1) / 2
set numstars to 1

# Gradually get wider until just before middle line.

while numspaces > 0:
    for i = 1 to numspaces: output " "
    for i = 1 to numstars:  output "*"
    output newline
    subtract 1 from numspaces
    add 2 to numstars

# Gradually get thinner until end.

while numstars > 0:
    for i = 1 to numspaces: output " "
    for i = 1 to numstars:  output "*"
    output newline
    add 1 to numspaces
    subtract 2 from numstars
```

And, as a final exercise, you can refactor:

```
    for i = 1 to numspaces: output " "
    for i = 1 to numstars:  output "*"
    output newline
```

into a separate function, since it's common between the two loops.

---

And now, since you've got your own code working, here's the Python code I used for proof of concept, included for completeness:

```
def lineout (sp, st):
    s = ""
    for i in range (sp): s = "%s "%(s)
    for i in range (st): s = "%s*"%(s)
    print s

n = 21
numspaces = (n-1) / 2
numstars = 1

while numspaces > 0:
    lineout (numspaces, numstars)
    numspaces -= 1
    numstars += 2

while numstars > 0:
    lineout (numspaces, numstars)
    numspaces += 1
    numstars -= 2
```

You could probably write it more succinctly in Python if you used the more modern features but that would rather defeat the purpose of quick understanding and easy translation. Just change `n` to whatever number you want (odd and greater than two, providing the resultant diamond will fit in your terminal) and enjoy the output :-)

```
          *
         ***
        *****
       *******
      *********
     ***********
    *************
   ***************
  *****************
 *******************
*********************
 *******************
  *****************
   ***************
    *************
     ***********
      *********
       *******
        *****
         ***
          *
```

Comment: I understand the whole concept that the spaces decrease and the stars increase and vice versa after the middle point when there is 0 spaces. What kind of if/else statement would I use to control whether a * or space gets printed though? Sorry, I am simply just a beginner trying to understand and learn this clearly.

Comment: @Mike, you don't use an `if` statement. If you want to print ten spaces and nine stars, that would be two consecutive `for` loops. Consecutive as in 'one after the other', in case I didn't make that clear, in which case I apologise.

Comment: I could only get the top left quarter of the diamond to print. Any suggestions? Take a look at my code.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: @Mike, see my answer, specifically the bit `"the star count increases by 2"` - you're only increasing by 1. My advice is to use separate variables for `numSpaces` and `numStars` so you're not worrying about on-the-fly calculations using a formula - just `-1/+2` getting wider and `+1/-2` getting thinner in _another_ loop following that.

Comment: I have came up with code that works for user input 5 but it doesn't work for any other odd positive integer other than 5. Instead the diamond becomes deformed. I posted my code. I will try to compare what I have to your pseudo-code. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

There are two things that occur here:

1. Indent changes (-1 to "mid", +1 "after")
2. Star count changes (+2 to "mid", -2 "after")

Now, this could be done with two loops (one for the top to "mid" and one "after"), but the values can also be determined with a little math. Let's explore *that* :-)

Here are the numbers:

```
        s(spaces)  x(stars) n(line number)
__X          2        1        0
_XXX         1        3        1
XXXXXX       0        5        2
_XXX         1        3        3
__X          2        1        4
```

Start by noting that `s` is symmetrical about the "mid":

- s = abs(2 - n)

And then that `x` is related to `s` (by 2 as noted in deltas above):

- x = 5 - (s * 2) = 5 - (abs(2 - n) * 2)

Hope that gives some insight!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably taking introductory C class right now, and as everyone else I would discourage you from copying, but for reference here is an answer:

To make the answer simple, all you need to know is how many spaces and stars to print.

The sequence is following: **[print spaces] [print stars] [print spaces] [print '\n']**.
Observe that in the middle row we would need: **(0) spaces, *(numStars)* stars, (0) spaces**.
In the row above and below, we would need: **(1) space, *(numStars - 2)* stars, (1) space**.
An so on...

This should give you the feeling that to count number of spaces, you need to count the distance from the middle row. Also note that with each row away from the middle, number of stars decreases by 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int num, middle, spaceCount, starCount;

    printf("Enter a num:");
    scanf("%d",&num);   

    middle = (num-1)/2;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){

        spaceCount = abs(middle - i);
        starCount = num - 2*abs(middle - i);

        for(int c = 0; c < spaceCount; c++)
            printf(" ");

        for(int c = 0; c < starCount; c++)
            printf("*");

        for(int c = 0; c < spaceCount; c++)
            printf(" ");

        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Since we are calculating the distance between the current row and the middle one, we need to know the absolute value. ***abs*** function is standard C function to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this a bit. Also sorry, my final code is C++, not strict C, as I haven't used C in 10 years. Here's a more wordy explanation for those trying to understand how to work this out for yourself. Before I begin, one thing you can do to help yourself out is start with a declaration like:

int numStars = 1, numSpaces = 10;

numSpaces doesn't really matter as long as it's small enough to fit on your screen... you can plug in any number and test it later. Then, work out your algorithm, and later on you can work on handling input.

Also, the number of spaces AFTER the stars is irrelevant for this problem.

Then, solve the problem of how to output the top portion of the diamond. I used a counter loop to print spaces until I'd printed the number of spaces for the first row, then a second loop (not nested) to print the number of stars needed for that row. We know that in row 1, we need to print a space 10 times and a star one time.

Once the row has the number of spaces and stars required, you go to the newline ("\n" or endl). But the next row you need to print 2 more stars and 1 less spaces. So you must increment/decrement appropriately.

When you get to the row before the middle row, you'll stop. In other words, the top loop needs to continue while numSpaces is greater than 0. At the end of thefinal pass in the loop, numSpaces is decremented to 0, but it won't print the line with 0 spaces and n stars (2 stars for every space you started with). That happens in your next loop...

Then, you can run the second loop that reverses your increment/decrement at the end, but is otherwise almost the same. Only this time, it should print 0 spaces and 10n stars. Then the newline, and finally decrease the numStars by 2 and increase numSpaces by 1.

If you're not using functions yet or not allowed to in implementation, that's just about it. You could easily call a function, though, passing it numSpaces/numStars, for each of the loops to eliminate duplicate code.

Here's my code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int     numStars = 1,
            numSpaces = 10;

    while (numSpaces > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numStars; i++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << "\n";

        numStars += 2;
        numSpaces--;
    }
    while (numStars > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numStars; i++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << "\n";
        numStars -= 2;
        numSpaces++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to give you the code, you should learn.

The input number will be the width of the diamond, so make sure to make a relation between the spaces and asterisks that does not surpass this number.

The main idea would be to start at 1 asterisk, and increment by two each time until the input number is reached.

Also, do something to prevent an error if the user enters an even number.

Comment: I have written in so that if the user does not enter a positive odd integer greater than 0, it will ask for input again. Just having a difficult time understanding when it will print "*" or " " given the users input.

Answer (score 0):

here the code with matlab

```
clear all, clc
n=input('Input an Odd Number ');
for i=1:(n+1)/2
    for m=1:(n+1)/2-i
        fprintf(' ');
    end
    for j=1:(2*i)-1
        fprintf('*');
    end
    fprintf('\n');
end
for k=i-1:-1:1
    for m=1:(n+1)/2-k
        fprintf(' ');
    end
    for j=1:(2*k)-1
        fprintf('*');
    end
    fprintf('\n');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {    //check this out more optimized code hope it will be help full.    
    for (int row=-2;row<=2;row++)
        {
        for (int col=-2;col<=2;col++)
        {
        if (Math.Abs(row)+Math.Abs(col)<=2)
        {
        Console.Write("*");
        }
        else
        {
        Console.Write(" ");
        }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: This will 100 and 10 percent help you out guarantee. And if you want a bigger diamond of users choice let them enter their choice and set that choice in place of -2 and 2 like for(int row=-choice;row<=choice;row++). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int i,j,k,n;
scanf("%d",&n);
n=(n+1)/2;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=n;j>=i;j--)
            printf(" ");
        for(k=1;k<=(2*i-1);k++)
            printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=1;i<=(n-1);i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
            printf(" ");
        for(k=(2*n-3);k>=(2*i-1);k--)
            printf("*");
        printf("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to *stackoverflow*, you might want to add some text to your answer in order to improve its quality.

Comment: By text you meant comments?

Comment: Something like that, yes, a short explanation of your solution; it enriches your answer considerably.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i got to best solution for this problem in less no of lines

```
int b=0;
for(int a=0;b<=50;a=(b<=25) ? a+2 : a-2 ){
    b+=2;
    for(int b=25-a;b>0;b-=2){
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(int c=0;c<=a;c++){
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Output a diamond in C by asterisk sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j95ne.png)

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int n, i, j;

printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

/* Create up arrow. */
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{   /* Left side. */
    for(j=i; j<=n+1; j++)
    {
        printf(" ");

    }
    for(j=1; j<=1; j++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    /* Middle. */
    for(j=1; j<i-1; j++)
    {
        printf(" ");

    }

    /* Right side. */
    for(j=1; j<i; j++)
    {
        printf(" ");

    }
    for(j=1; j<=1; j++)
    {
        if(i!=n-(n-1))
            printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
/* Create down arrow. */
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{   /* Left side. */
    for(j=1; j<=i+2; j++)
    {
        printf(" ");

    }
    for(j=1; j<=1; j++)
    {
        if(i!=n)
        printf("*");
    }
    /* Middle. */
    for(j=i; j<n-2; j++)
    {
        printf(" ");

    }
    /* Right side. */
    for(j=i; j<n-1; j++)
    {
        printf(" ");

    }
    for(j=1; j<=1; j++)
    {
        if(i<n-1)
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```