# Generating 1s and 0s and storing in a diamond shape inside a array

Tags: c, arrays, shapes

I have an assignment which consists of creating a piece of code that generates and stores values in the shape:

```
1 1 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 1
1 1 0 1 1
```

I may use only arrays and loops. It's no necessary to print the array but I'm printing it just to check if I've done correctly. In my head this should work, but it returns garbage. The array is two dimensional, must have equal odd numbered sizes. I have literally less than one week of experience with any sort of programing.

```
main(){
    int number;
    printf("PLEASE GIVE ME A EVEN NUMBER FROM 3 TO 20\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if(number%2==0)
    {
        printf("THIS WON'T FIT\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int array1[number][number];
    int lin, col, zero=1, count;
    int ones=(number-1)/2;
    for(lin=0;lin<number;lin++)
    {
        for(col=0;col<number;col++)
        {
            for(count=1; count<=ones;count++)
            {
                array1[lin][col]=1;

                for(count=1;count<=zero;count++)
                {
                    array1[lin][col]=0;
                }
            }
        }

        --ones;
        zero+=2;
    }

    for(lin=0;lin<number;lin++)
    {
        for(col=0;col<number;col++)
            printf("%d", array1[lin][col]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Same thing of previous post: time to learn how to debug your code.

Comment: The wicked messages.

Comment: Given points `i` and `j`, can you check whether the point is inside/outside diamond?

Comment: Since you seem to be using C99/C11 on a hosted system, `main()` is not valid C. All functions in modern C must return void or a value. In the specific case of `main()`, you are only allowed to use one of the forms specified by the compiler. Usually it is `int main (void)`.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456654/print-star-diamond-in-c-with-nested-loops)

Comment: You ask for an even number, then complain when you get one. Make up your mind.

Comment: Uh typos. It's a odd number. That diamond can't be made in a even matrix, I was planning using some sort of mahattan distance algorithim but my 1 class of programming don't allow me. (After a circle in manhattan distance would be aproximatelly that)

Comment: Too many nested `for` loops, use functions if the assignment allows. If it doesn't, the assignment doesn't make sense now because it encourages bad programming practices.

Comment: My teacher encourages bad pratices, I almost got an assignment refused because it didn't had system("pause"). (I'm learning to use linux at the same time I learn C so I just use vim or nano.) Isn't the problem here one of algorthimic nature?. Lundin although that is not the problem, thanks for the info.

Comment: *My teacher encourages bad pratices*, maybe you can follow his advice and stop attending his classes?

Comment: I can't. His the only teacher available and it's a mandatory class.  (The guy even uses a discontinued IDE [devc++]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int number;
    printf("PLEASE GIVE ME A ODD NUMBER FROM 3 TO 19\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if(number%2==0 || number < 3 || number > 19){
        printf("THIS WON'T FIT\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int center = number / 2;
    int array[number][number];

    for(int i = 0; i < number; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < number; ++j){
            array[i][j] = abs(i-center)+abs(j-center) > center;
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is the negative of what OP ask for. ;) `array[i][j] = !(abs(i-center)+abs(j-center) <= center);`

Comment: @LPs or replace `<=` by `>`

Comment: @Matthieu Yes, for sure ;)

Comment: Thanks bluepixy, that is what I "had" mind for the manhattan/taxicab/whatever distance but coudn't put into code because of the lack of practice and well, bad teacher...